# Method to multiply 2 two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to create a method that takes 2 Two-dim array as parameters and print their multiplication array(be like matrix multiplication in method). seems like it is stuck somewhere in an infinite loop during runtime. any modification?

```
public static void multiplicationOfArray(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2) {
    int row1 = matrix1.length;
    int column1 = matrix1[0].length;
    int row2 = matrix2.length;
    int column2 = matrix2[0].length;
    int[][] resultmatrix = new int[row1][column2];

    if (column1 == row2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row1; row1++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < column2; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < column1; k++) {
                    resultmatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < row1; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < column2; column++) {
                System.out.println(resultmatrix[row][column] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < row1; row1++) {` looks like it should be `for (int i = 0; i < row1; i++) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dimensions is not right/valid then you may throw an exception. 
You may also try this method -

```
public static double[][] multiply(double[][] A, double[][] B) {
        int mA = A.length;
        int nA = A[0].length;
        int mB = B.length;
        int nB = B[0].length;
        if (nA != mB) throw new RuntimeException("Illegal matrix dimensions.");
        double[][] C = new double[mA][nB];
        for (int i = 0; i < mA; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nB; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < nA; k++)
                    C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        return C;
    }
```

A full code can be found [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/22library/Matrix.java.html).

Comment: Thanks buddy, very useful link! :)

Comment: O(n^3) solution. You could try to optimize this. Read about the [Strassen algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) which tries to solve it in O(n^2.8)

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop conditions are a bit mixed up. For example this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row1; row1++) {
```

will only terminate when `i` is greater than `row1` however, at no point in the remaining code or loops do you increase the value of `i` or reduce the value of `row1`, therefore the condition `i >= row1` will never be met.

Try this instead:

```
public static void multiplicationOfArray(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2) {
    int row1 = matrix1.length;
    int coloumn1 = matrix1[0].length;
    int row2 = matrix2.length;
    int coloumn2 = matrix2[0].length;
    int[][] resultmatrix = new int[row1][coloumn2];

    if (coloumn1 == row2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < coloumn2; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < coloumn1; k++) {
                    resultmatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        for (int row = 0; row < row1; row++) {
            for (int coloumn = 0; coloumn < coloumn2; coloumn++) {
                System.out.println(resultmatrix[row][coloumn] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```